# Setting up Reverse SSH Socks Proxy Tunnel or Openvpn Node from inside my schools network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, proxy, openvpn

I've had this idea where I use some of the raspberry pi's I have laying around as Openvpn Nodes or a machine that's inside my schools LAN.

So obviously the question here is HOW can I facilitate dropping a Pi on a network that's either public or I have only the wifi password for and be able to connect out to the wlan? (no admin privs)

Would it be possible to change the SSH port to 443 or something like that and be able to connect out that way?

This is my first post on here. I would really appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should definitely follow any and all rules your school/district has in place.
2. There's a chance the network admins are doing some form of DPI (deep packet inspection). This means that just changing the SSH connection to TCP/443 won't be enough. You'll need to wrap whatever connection you want to make in SSL/TLS. A VPN that can do this is openconnect.

So I would use some SSL wrapped VPN protocol running on TCP/443. That'll look the most like a standard HTTPS connection.

Comment: So how should I change my SSH config file to be wrapped in my Openconnect VPN connection?